# Find all NULL values and set them to lowest unused number using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I want to **find all** `NULL` **values** in column `parameter_id` and **set them to lowest unused** `parameter_id`.

I have query which will find lowest unused `parameter_id`, I also know how to get list of `NULL` values.

```
SELECT MIN(t1.parameter_id)+1 FROM table AS t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.parameter_id = t1.parameter_id+1)
```

I can get list of all rows with `parameter_id=NULL`, then make query to find current lowest unused `parameter_id` and then update `parameter_id` to that lowest unused number. Since table has 50.000 rows, this approach would create thousands of queries (50.000 * 2 per row).

Is there way to run "single query" which will find all `parameter_id=NULL` and update them all to current lowest unused `parameter_id`?

**Here is table decrtiption (MySQL 5.5):**

```
id (INT) primary key, auto_increment
parameter_id (INT) default NULL
```

**Sample data:**

```
# id, parameter_id
1, NULL
2, 1
3, NULL
4, 5
5, 3
```

**Desired result:**

```
# id, parameter_id
1, 2
2, 1
3, 4
4, 5
5, 3
```

**EDIT:**

I distilled what I want to single query. I simply need to run this query until there is 0 rows affected by UPDATE.

```
UPDATE `table`
SET parameter_id=
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT MIN(t1.parameter_id)+1
      FROM `table` AS t1
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT *
           FROM `table` AS t2
           WHERE t2.parameter_id = t1.parameter_id+1)) AS t4)
WHERE parameter_id IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Every row has to have current lowest unused parameter_id. After you update single row, current lowest unused parameter_id will change.

Comment: using sql server, the following works: update   t set parameter_id = 
(SELECT MIN(t1.parameter_id)+1 FROM t AS t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t AS t2 WHERE t2.parameter_id = t1.parameter_id+1)) 
where parameter_id is null

Comment: Oh, but I have MySQL/MariaDB and can't change it to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

The following enumerates the unused parameter ids:

```
select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.parameter_id = t.id)
order by t.id;
```

(You might want to put this in a temporary table with an index on `seqnum` for the subsequent query.)

The problem is getting a join key for the `update`.  Here is a bit of a kludge:  I'm going to add a column, enumerate it, and then drop it:

```
alter table `table` add column null_seqnum;

update `table` t cross join (select @rn1 := 0) params
    set null_seqnum = (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1)
    where parameter_id is null;

update `table` t join
       (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
        from `table` t cross join
             (select @rn := 0) params
        where not exists (select 1 from `table` t2 where t2.parameter_id = t.id)
        order by t.id
       ) tnull
       on t.null_seqnum = tnull.seqnum
    set t.parameter_id = tnull.id;

alter table `table` drop column null_seqnum;
```

Comment: This will take me a while to grasp. Btw, what is "@rn", what is ":="? Just give me a hint/link so I can lookit in documentation.

Comment: Didn't know about variables. Thanks @Strawberry

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I ran queries but it did not work. It will set null_seqnum=3 to all rows where parameter_id IS NULL and that is it.

Comment: There are missing ` around name "table" two times, and missing alias name "t" after `table`, also two times. Query works after repair, but it does nothing other than setting null_seqnum to 3.